# Why am I getting this error in android studio: error: failed to load XML file: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)

Tags: android, reactjs, native

I'm completely new to android studio. When I type npm start in the terminal to run the newly created project in the android emulator I get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to load XML file: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).

When I check in file explorer AndroidManifest.xml is where it should be? Here's the full log.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject> npm start

> AwesomeProject@0.0.1 start
> react-native start

```
                    ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                 ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
              ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
             ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
             ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
              ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                 ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                    ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒


            Welcome to Metro v0.76.5
          Fast - Scalable - Integrated
```

r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Installing the app...

> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in D:\Android_Studio_SDK\licenses
> License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
> "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Tools in D:\Android_Studio_SDK\tools
> "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" finished.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in D:\Android_Studio_SDK\licenses
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in D:\Android_Studio_SDK\build-tools\30.0.3
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
> Task :app:buildCodegenCLI SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED
> Task :app:generatePackageList
> Task :app:preBuild
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> 31 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor
/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Windows\System32\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to load XML file: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I followed the environment setup instructions Documentation on react native.